# How to convert quaternion to angle?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, motion

Is there a formula to convert a quaternion to an angle?

Looking to do something on the iPhone using the Core Motion API and the gyro so that based on data I receive from it (in the form of quaternions) I can project a UIView on the screen.

Thanks

Comment: Does this do it? It's math, not code, but you can probably make the leap from one to the other. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, see [Quaternions and spatial rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation).  The unit quaternion (w, x, y, z) represents a rotation about the axis (x, y, z) of an angle of 2*cos<sup>-1</sup>(w).

Note that this is only true of *unit* quaternions.  Non-unit quaternions do not represent rotations.

Comment: Is this going to give me both the horizontal and vertical angles?  Again, I'm working with an iPhone 4 and try to project a UIView on to the screen based on how the phone is being held.  thanks

Comment: Also note, that you need to use the *absolute value* of w to get the minimal angle.