# Convert 2 angles (spherical rotation) to single angle (quaternion)

Tags: 3d, latitude-longitude, quaternions, spherical-coordinate

I have 2 angles, `phi` (left-right rotation) and `psi` (up-down rotation). I want to convert them to a single angle, which would be the equivalent of a quaternion (=smallest rotation around a unit vector).

From this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47277997/113718
we get that the spherical -> quaternion conversion would give:
`quat = (cos(phi/2)cos(psi/2), -sin(phi/2)sin(psi/2), cos(phi/2)sin(psi/2), sin(phi/2)cos(psi/2))`

Now, from another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3825595/113718
the angle of the quaternion is

angle = 2 * cos<sup>-1</sup>(w) = 2 * cos<sup>-1</sup>( sin(phi/2)cos(psi/2) )

However this doesn't seem right. I would expect that when

`phi = 0 => angle = psi`, and vice versa when `psi = 0 => angle = phi`

but this doesn't seem to be the case with the formula above. What am I comprehending wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first link looks like it is a "scalar first" convention (i.e., w is the first element). So you should be looking at the cos(phi/2)*cos(psi/2) term for the angle. Then everything works out for you as expected when phi=0 and when psi=0.

angle = 2 * cos^-1(w) = 2 * cos^-1( cos(phi/2)cos(psi/2) )